# Claim Based Auth Webapplication issue in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, claims-based-auth

I have done FBA configuration in IIS. I am getting success to login through FBA User. But when click on sign out through any SharePoint user or FBA user, it will give error

```
"Exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' was thrown. Parameter name: encodedValue"
```

I note that When click on sign out it will redirect to "`/SiteURL`" not to "`/SiteURL/_login/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F&Source=%2F`".

I dont know what happen..

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

You can define custom signout URL with PowerShell.

`Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage -identity "Signout" -RelativePath "/_layouts/customsignout.aspx" -WebApplication "http://server_name/mywebapp"`

You can view the current signout page with

`Get-SPCustomLayoutsPage -Identity "Signout" -WebApplication "http://server_name/mywebapp"`

Comment: Thanx @Jussi Palo... I dont know how to make custom sign out page? Can you guide me with some code? Thanx in advance...

Comment: If you would see if there is some custom value set for the signout page, if yes, then revert the setting back to default signout page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the web application to use FormsAuth in Central Administration? Sounds like the web application doesn't know where to send the correct signout requests...

Comment: But how can i set signout page from Central Administration?

Comment: You don't, you set the application to use Forms Auth in Central Admin, and then SharePoint knows where to send users on sign out

Comment: i have created one customsignout page. It contain code for delete FormAuthentication cookies but only for FBA Users. I also want to delete Sharepoint users credential and cookies. How? If you know then guide me.

Comment: What I'm saying is that if you use FormsAuth as specified in Central Admin, you do not need a custom signout page.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error after creating a Team site on SP2013 with out of the box Claims Authentication.

The issue occurred because FIPs was enabled on the server. It seems that the STS token provider is not FIPs compatible.  Disabling FIPs was what did it for me.

http://opensourcesharepoint.blogspot.kr/2013/05/systemargumentexception-when-you-create.html